# How can I put a custom meta box above the editor but below the title section on the edit post page?

Tags: post-editor, metabox

I have a custom meta box for a custom post type that my client wants placed between the title/permalink section and the post editor in the admin panel.  Is this possible and if so is there a hook/filter/etc that I would need to use?

Comment: Very similar question here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35416/re-order-editor-to-be-after-meta-box

Answer (score 58, accepted):

- Simply add a meta box using the *advanced* context, and *high* priority
- Then, latch on to the `edit_form_after_title` hook
- Print your meta boxes out there, then remove it so it doesn't appear twice.

  ```
  // Move all "advanced" metaboxes above the default editor
  add_action('edit_form_after_title', function() {
      global $post, $wp_meta_boxes;
      do_meta_boxes(get_current_screen(), 'advanced', $post);
      unset($wp_meta_boxes[get_post_type($post)]['advanced']);
  });
  ```

Comment: A site I'm working on registers some metaboxes using the `register_meta_box_cb` parameter of the `register_post_type` function. I've tried your code but the metaboxes don't move above the editor. Can this be used in my case? Thanks

Comment: I would recommend using a custom `$context`, instead of `advanced`, use something like `my_before_editor`, so that you do not move all meta boxes in the `advanced` context, you specifically target your specific meta boxes .. see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/

Comment: `edit_form_after_title` not supported by block editor https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/5821

Answer (score 18):

Here is how you can move **specific** meta boxes above the editor, but before I post the code I just would like to thank Andrew and mhulse. You guys rock!

```
function foo_deck( $post_type ) {
    if ( in_array( $post_type, array( 'post', 'page' ) ) ) {
        add_meta_box(
            'contact_details_meta',
            'Contact Details',
            'contact_details_meta',
            $post_type,
            'test', // change to something other then normal, advanced or side
            'high'
        );
    }
}

add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'foo_deck');

function foo_move_deck() {
        # Get the globals:
        global $post, $wp_meta_boxes;

        # Output the "advanced" meta boxes:
        do_meta_boxes( get_current_screen(), 'test', $post );

        # Remove the initial "advanced" meta boxes:
        unset($wp_meta_boxes['post']['test']);
    }

add_action('edit_form_after_title', 'foo_move_deck');
```

Comment: `change to something other then normal, advanced or side` -was the key in my case. Thanks for the info.

Comment: This was the most helpful answer to me. Thank you!

Answer (score 13):

To provide a full code example based on Andrew's answer ... I needed a way to include a "Deck" (aka subhead) to my posts; I wanted the deck field to appear after the main title bar.

```
/**
 * Add a "deck" (aka subhead) meta box to post page(s) and position it
 * under the title.
 *
 * @todo Move to class.
 * @see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box
 * @see http://wordpress.org/extend/ideas/topic/add-meta-box-to-multiple-post-types
 * @see https://github.com/Horttcore/WordPress-Subtitle
 * @see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nonce_field
 */

# Adds a box to the main column on the Post and Page edit screens:
function foo_deck($post_type) {

    # Allowed post types to show meta box:
    $post_types = array('post', 'page');

    if (in_array($post_type, $post_types)) {

        # Add a meta box to the administrative interface:
        add_meta_box(
            'foo-deck-meta-box', // HTML 'id' attribute of the edit screen section.
            'Deck',              // Title of the edit screen section, visible to user.
            'foo_deck_meta_box', // Function that prints out the HTML for the edit screen section.
            $post_type,          // The type of Write screen on which to show the edit screen section.
            'advanced',          // The part of the page where the edit screen section should be shown.
            'high'               // The priority within the context where the boxes should show.
        );

    }

}

# Callback that prints the box content:
function foo_deck_meta_box($post) {

    # Use `get_post_meta()` to retrieve an existing value from the database and use the value for the form:
    $deck = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_deck', true);

    # Form field to display:
    ?>

        <label class="screen-reader-text" for="foo_deck">Deck</label>
        <input id="foo_deck" type="text" autocomplete="off" value="<?=esc_attr($deck)?>" name="foo_deck" placeholder="Deck">

    <?php

    # Display the nonce hidden form field:
    wp_nonce_field(
        plugin_basename(__FILE__), // Action name.
        'foo_deck_meta_box'        // Nonce name.
    );

}

/**
 * @see https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/16267/32387
 */

# Save our custom data when the post is saved:
function foo_deck_save_postdata($post_id) {

    # Is the current user is authorised to do this action?
    if ((($_POST['post_type'] === 'page') && current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id) || current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id))) { // If it's a page, OR, if it's a post, can the user edit it? 

        # Stop WP from clearing custom fields on autosave:
        if ((( ! defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE')) || ( ! DOING_AUTOSAVE)) && (( ! defined('DOING_AJAX')) || ( ! DOING_AJAX))) {

            # Nonce verification:
            if (wp_verify_nonce($_POST['foo_deck_meta_box'], plugin_basename(__FILE__))) {

                # Get the posted deck:
                $deck = sanitize_text_field($_POST['foo_deck']);

                # Add, update or delete?
                if ($deck !== '') {

                    # Deck exists, so add OR update it:
                    add_post_meta($post_id, '_deck', $deck, true) OR update_post_meta($post_id, '_deck', $deck);

                } else {

                    # Deck empty or removed:
                    delete_post_meta($post_id, '_deck');

                }

            }

        }

    }

}

# Get the deck:
function foo_get_deck($post_id = FALSE) {

    $post_id = ($post_id) ? $post_id : get_the_ID();

    return apply_filters('foo_the_deck', get_post_meta($post_id, '_deck', TRUE));

}

# Display deck (this will feel better when OOP):
function foo_the_deck() {

    echo foo_get_deck(get_the_ID());

}

# Conditional checker:
function foo_has_subtitle($post_id = FALSE) {

    if (foo_get_deck($post_id)) return TRUE;

}

# Define the custom box:
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'foo_deck');
# Do something with the data entered:
add_action('save_post', 'foo_deck_save_postdata');

/**
 * @see https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36600
 * @see https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/94530/
 */

# Now move advanced meta boxes after the title:
function foo_move_deck() {

    # Get the globals:
    global $post, $wp_meta_boxes;

    # Output the "advanced" meta boxes:
    do_meta_boxes(get_current_screen(), 'advanced', $post);

    # Remove the initial "advanced" meta boxes:
    unset($wp_meta_boxes['post']['advanced']);

}

add_action('edit_form_after_title', 'foo_move_deck');
```

Obviously, the code above could use some more work, but it should help others trying to do the same stuff (Andrew's answer shined light, but I thought it might be helpful to actually provide a working example).

[This answer also helped](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/94530/).

Improvements that could be made:

1. Make OOP/class(es).
2. Add styles/js to make it look/feel/behave like the title field.

I plan on making the above improvements at some point in future, but at least the above code should help others trying to figure this out.

See [source code here](https://github.com/Horttcore/WordPress-Subtitle) for more inspiration (they opted to use jQuery to move the "sub-title").

Comment: In case it helps anyone going down the same path: I've asked a [question here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/99039/filtering-the-title-with-option-to-return-subhead) which has some related/similar code (I opted to use the "title" field to hold and filter the subhead).

Answer (score 8):

Instead of moving everything in the advanced section to the top, why not create a new section and move that to the top:

```
// Create 'top' section and move that to the top
add_action('edit_form_after_title', function() {
  global $post, $wp_meta_boxes;
  do_meta_boxes(get_current_screen(), 'top', $post);
  unset($wp_meta_boxes[get_post_type($post)]['top']);
});
```

Now all you need to do is register the meta box using `top` for the section and `high` for the priority.

It's working on WordPress 4.4.2 for me. I haven't tested this on other WP versions.

Answer (score 1):

There is an other way, by the way we can put the editor to any position:

1. Remove editor from support param when you register post_type
2. add a fake metabox

   ```
   add_meta_box( 'does-not-matter', 
   __( 'Description'), 
   function($post){ 
     wp_editor($post->post_content,'post_content',array('name'=>'post_content'));
   },
   'post_type_type', 
   'advanced', 
   'high' );
   ```

Comment: FYI, this still works, but when you move the box it causes some weird behavior with the content of the field. Users beware.