# Any way to get more space for editing post excerpts

Tags: excerpt, block-editor

Using latest WP with Gutenberg. The excerpt metabox is (as you'd expect) over in the right column with the Document settings.

Is there any way to get it out of that column and into the main area where the textarea would then be of a *useful* size?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the context, in which you would like to make these changes, I'd simply remove the metabox from that certain post type. Then add another metabox above the editor for your excerpt box.

The downside: you can not use get_the_excerpt, the_excerpt etc. anymore because that metabox doesn't exist any more.

Have a look at this post

[How can I put a custom meta box above the editor but below the title section on the edit post page?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36600/how-can-i-put-a-custom-meta-box-above-the-editor-but-below-the-title-section-on/158485#158485)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to *move* the Excerpt field into the main block editor area, but you can get a much wider and more usable Excerpt field by adding a few admin CSS rules that widen the edit-post-sidebar on hover.

The solution below widens the sidebar by up to 300% when you hover over it.

1. **Create an Admin CSS** file in your child theme folder called `admin-style.css`
2. **Add custom CSS** to your new file

*Add to `admin-style.css`*

```
/*
For larger viewports, widen the edit post sidebar when hovered over
*/
@media screen and (min-width: 782px) {
    .edit-post-layout.is-sidebar-opened .edit-post-sidebar:hover {
        width: 700px;
        max-width: 50vw;
        transition: all ease .7s;
    }
}
```

3. **Enqueue admin style** by placing this code in `functions.php`

*Add to `functions.php`*

```
// Enqueue custom admin style sheet
function load_custom_wp_admin_style() {
    wp_register_style( 'custom_wp_admin_css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/admin-style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_wp_admin_css' );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_custom_wp_admin_style' );
```

By using `admin_enqueue_scripts`, this file is only loaded on the admin side and will not impact the publicly-visible frontend of your website.

Comment: That's a nice tweak. like it.

Comment: this is a _really_ nice tweak. Particularly with the clear instrux how to correctly enqueue the admin CSS.

Comment: Glad you like it. This admin-style comes in handy for other admin tweaks too.