# Whats the point of returning a value in AUTO_SAVE

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, metabox, autosave

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Return $post_id when DOING_AUTOSAVE?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14169/return-post-id-when-doing-autosave)

```
if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
    return $post_id;
}
```

I always see this in custom made themes, but is it really necessary to return a value if you're trying to get auto save to not do anything? why not just leave it empty or return false.

Comment: If it is an action handler you don’t have to return anything.

Comment: yes its part of the function that goes into 

add_action('save_post, 'function_name')

I can just leave it blank correct?

Comment: Correct, `save_post` is an action, and `do_action()` (the function calling it) will not use any return value. That is not restricted to `DOING_AUTOSAVE`.